# When clipping an input vector layer with many polygons, polygons which overlap the boundary of the clip layer are not included in clipped layer

Tags: qgis-3, geoprocessing, clip

[image]This seems like a simple issue, but searching all the questions and answers here I cannot find the solution. I have a vector file made up of many polygons (it is a layer of vegetation types). I want to clip this layer based on my study area (which is a single polygon). The steps I have followed:

Vector: Geoprocessing Tools: Clip: Vegetation type (input layer) + Study area (Clip layer)

Issue is, the resultant Clipped layer around the boundaries does not include the polygons that overlap the study area and vegetation type boundary (i.e. it has not split these polygons at the clip boundary and included them in the Clipped layer - which is what I want to happen). All the polygons that are fully enclosed in within the clip boundary are included in the Clipped layer as expected.

Is there something I am missing here?

**Image description:** Green = vegetation type (Input layer), Red dash Line = study area (Clip layer) and Orange = Clipped layer (the result layer). My need is to have all the polygons on the right side of the red dash line in image as orange.

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: QGIS 3 @ahmadhanb

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour with a simple test dataset - the polygons that are only partially in the study area do get split for me. Could you edit your question to include a sample of the data that's causing problems?

Comment: Thanks @Jake. Have added an image above of issue. Does this help or do you need more.

Comment: Did you have some features selected prior to performing the clip? If so it may have only applied the clip to the selected features.

Comment: @Liam G thanks for comment. No features selected prior to clip.

Comment: Ok try applying a buffer to the vegetation layer, with distance set to 0, then do the clip. Might be invalid geometries resulting in only some features getting clipped. The zero distance buffer has helped me get rid of invalid geometries in the past

Comment: @Liam G. Thanks for tip. Applied buffer = 0 to Vegetation type layer as suggested and then proceed to clip using the resultant Buffered layer but has generated the same result as the original clip

Comment: @user159948: From the screenshot, it looks like clipping the features did work correctly: There are black lines indicating the feature boundaries underneath the dashed red line. What are the orange areas: Are they a separate layer, or are they a feature class within the vegetation layer? Can you try hiding all layers except for the results layer and checking whether the results layer looks correct?

Comment: @Jake Included when I added image was basically this description (I don't know how you make the image description visible in post). Green = vegetation type (Input layer), Red dash Line = study area (Clip layer) and Orange = Clipped layer (the result layer). My need is to have all the polygons on the right side of the red dash line in image as orange. You are correct the polygons are split under the red dash line (clip layer), but that is an artefact of the layer creation - the polygons were created within regions and I am using one of those regions (my study area) to clip. But just cant do it.

Comment: @user159948: That's really odd. Are both layers using the same CRS? Would it be possible for you to share an extract of the data so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Jake Problem solved! Thanks very much for all your help with this. My error - CRS different on layers. Set to GDA 94 and works as expected. Again thanks!

Comment: @user159948: Fantastic, I'm glad it works now! I'm a bit surprised that this problem was caused by different CRS's, because they should be [automatically reprojected](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/4702#issue-124792934). It would be great if you could [open a bug report](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues) including some sample data so this can be fixed.